# How to Create a table in C that consists of Arrays of fixed lenght

Tags: c, linked-list, lookup-tables

I am trying to implement a search table that basically consists of  arrays of a fixed size. In my case each array would consist of 4 elements (Say for ex letters W,X, Y and Z). I need each element in the array to have a fixed index in the table using which it can be found and accessed by the user. The table would something like this..( the symbol | is used below to show the ending of that particular array)

```
    WXYZ|XYWZ|WXZY|....|.... and so on
```

Could somebody tell me which is the best way to implement htis? I have heard of linked lists and hash tables but I am not sure if that is the best method to do this..

Comment: What did you try? Hash-tables fit well!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I was first trying to figure out which might be the best. Only after this I will start the implementation part.

Comment: In C99, a  `struct` can have some members which are fixed length arrays, and it might end with a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Actually the problem here is that I need a fixed number of jumbs to occur within the table. This jump will then give the value stored at that particular position ,unlike hash function where a unique index is generated everytime. SO mainly I just need an idea to create a table with these arrays in it..

Comment: Spend several hours reading a book on algorithms & data structures.

Comment: I think what Basile is saying, in part, is _show an example of what you have tried_.  It is more effective on this forum to ask for help on some existing thing that isn't quite right, then to ask someone to fabricate the thing from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get it, why don't you just use an ordinary two dimensional array like array[100][4], the user can access through an ordered pair of two indexes.